# Matlab - Slicing an Array without using additional memory

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory-management, parallel-processing

I want to slice an 4D-array into n parts along the 5th Dimension in order to use it in parfor:

```
X(:,:,:,particles)-->X(:,:,:,particles/n,n)
```

The Problem is that X is so big that  I run out of memory if I start writing it into a new variable, so i want to basically do:

```
X = cat(5,X(:,:,:,1:particles/n),X(:,:,:,particles/n+1:2*particles/n),...)
```

I am doing this with

```
sliced = 'cat(5'
for i=1:n
    sliced = strcat(2,sliced,sprintf(',X(:,:,:,(1+(%i-1)*%i):%i*%i)',i,particles/n,i,particles/n))
end
sliced = strcat(2,sliced,')');
X = eval(sliced);
```

I get:

```
Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
```

If i print out the contents of sliced and comment everything and paste the printout of sliced manually into eval('...') it works.

Anyone got a solution for my problem or another way of slicing a 4D array without using additional memory?

Thanks

Comment: OK, I think I have found my problem: strcat(2,...) adds an undefined character to the beginning of sliced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I just got things mixed up cat and strcat are not the same... oops :o

```
n           = 4;
particles   = 200;
X           = rand(6,6,6,particles);

sliced  = sprintf('X = cat(5'); 

for i = 1:n
     sliced = cat(2,sliced,sprintf(',X(:,:,:,(1+(%i-1)*%i):%i*%i)',i,particles/n,i,particles/n));
end

sliced = cat(2,sliced,sprintf(');'));
eval(sliced);
```

works just fine. If somebody has got a better way to slice without memory usage - please feel free to post...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)**, which must not use any additional memory -

```
sz_X = size(X) %// get size
X = reshape(X,sz_X(1),sz_X(2),sz_X(3),sz_X(4)/n,[]); %// reshape and save 
              %// into same variable and as such must be memory efficient
```